# Convertendo uma string para int?

Tags: c#, .net, conversão-de-tipo

Qual a melhor forma de converter uma variável `string` para uma outra variável do tipo `int?`, ou seja, um `nullable` de `int`? A performance é muito importante nesse caso porque estarei convertendo vários valores dentro de um loop.

Seria possível fazer essa conversão em uma linha de código? Pergunto isso porque serão muitas linhas de código consecutivas fazendo esta operação e seria um "plus" se não aumentasse muito meu código só com conversão de dados.

Comment: Se você tiver uma lista de strings (ou `IEnumerable<string>`) para converter, poderia usar LINQ, como indiquei na minha resposta. Dá para fazer em 2 ou 3 linhas de código assim... dependendo da formatação de código que você usar.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Você pode usar a seguinte função para fazer a conversão de forma eficaz e sem muitas linhas:

```
public static int? StringToNullableInt(string strNum)
{
    int outInt;
    return int.TryParse(strNum, out outInt) ? outInt : (int?)null;
}
```

Ou então para fazer as conversões inline, usando LINQ, você poderia fazer assim:

```
var strNumeros = new[] { "1267", "-835", "9", "", "xpto" };
int outInt;
var valores = strNumeros
    .Select(strNumero => int.TryParse(strNumero, out outInt) ? outInt : (int?)null)
    .ToList();
```

Dessa forma você converte todas as strings em um `IEnumerable<string>` em praticamente algumas linhas.

Answer (score 6):

Você também pode implementar a resposta do @MiguelAngelo na forma de extensão de classe:

```cs
namespace SeuProjeto.Extensions 
{
    public static class StringExtension 
    {
        public static Nullable<int> ToInt(this String value) 
        {
            int outInt;
            return int.TryParse(value, out outInt) ? outInt : (int?)null;
        }
    }
}
```

O mesmo exemplo em LINQ ficaria assim:

```cs
var strNumeros = new[] { "1267", "-835", "9", "", "xpto" };
int outInt;
var valores = strNumeros
    .Select(strNumero => strNumero.ToInt())
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 4):

É possível que existam várias formas de o fazer. Eu uso o `TryParse` para converter `string` para `int`.

Exemplo:

```
var varStringConvert = "123";
int varInt;
if ((int.TryParse(varStringConvert.ToString(), out varInt))) { 

}
```

O código acima apresenta a variável `varStringConvert` com o valor `123` que é inteiro mas o compilador como não adivinha e pensa que é uma variável do tipo `string`. Então temos de tentar converter para inteiro. Assim faço um `TryParse` da `string` para a variável `int` `varInt`.

Answer (score 2):

Pode ser usado a classe `Convert`. para converter uma `string` definida anteriormente, como por exemplo:

string name = "12345";

Convert.ToInt32(name);

Comment: Também resulta, mas caso não faça a conversão dá logo erro

Answer (score 1):

Converte e verifica se conseguiu converter ou não:

```
string str = '0123'; // ou qualquer coisa
int i = 0; // inicializa variável que receberá o valor inteiro

// Tenta converter str para inteiro (com saída na variável i)
if (Int32.TryParse(str, out i)) {
    Console.WriteLine(i); // Se conseguiu imprime variável
} else {
    Console.WriteLine ("Erro ao converter '" + str + "' para inteiro."); // Mensagme de erro
}
```

ou

```
string str = '0123'; // ou qualquer coisa
int i = 0; // inicializa variável que receberá o valor inteiro    
try
{
    i = Convert.ToInt32(str);
    Console.WriteLine(i); // Se conseguiu imprime variável
}
catch (FormatException e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("String inválida para conversão."); // Erro
}
catch (OverflowException e)
{
    Console.WriteLine ("Overflow. Valor inteiro ultrapassou o limtie."); // Erro
}
```

Crie uma classe específica para resolver isso e chame um método que você vai confiar, ou seja, você vai invocar um método para resolver essa conversão e vai ter a certeza que mesmo que a string seja inválida ele vá retornar um valor inteiro pra você.

Exemplo, se você só precisar de valores inteiros positivos, sempre que a função te retornar -1 seria sinal que deu erro. Etc.

A manutenção do código seria feita e em apenas um local, dentro desse método na determinada classe que resolve esse problema de conversão.

A performance não é influência diretamente em ambos os casos. Caso tenha certeza que o valor é inteiro, não verificar ganharia pouca performance, o que na minha opinião não vale a pena, já que um 'crash' na aplicação seria pior caso o sua função recebesse uma string que não contesse um possível valor inteiro.

Answer (score 0):

Existem pelo menos três tipos de conversões (Parse,TryParse e Convert) , o ideal, seria você entender como elas trabalham e usar elas de acordo com sua necessidade.

Você pode entender mais a respeito delas no post que deixo abaixo escrito pelo Vitor Mendes (MVP) que explica esse assunto:

[Parse, Convert ou TryParse](http://www.vitormendes.com.br/2013/01/17/parse-convert-ou-tryparse/)